# What do I need for a small drain in a basement sauna floor with poured concrete?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain

I am installing a drain in a basement sauna. I am pouring 4 inches of concrete over an existing concrete floor. I need to fit the drain and pipe in that 4 inches. The drain will not be subject to a high flow like a shower, and will not be tied directly into the sewer. The drain will be about 3 feet or so from the output and I know it will need space to slope towards the outlet.

What exactly do I need to buy for the drain and pipe? Can I fit that in 4 inches of concrete? How do you pour concrete in around it?

Comment: what's  the outlet?

Comment: TBD but likely some sort of hose that gets pumped into a utility sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a [side outlet drain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075LZCYLS).

The dimensions is less than 3 inches high, so you have room to shim under the drain to get the 1/4" / foot slope that is recommended.

You did not state what the drain will terminate into, so you may or may not need a trap.

With the PVC pipe glued in place, add what shims are needed under the drain and tape the pipe in place to hold the unit while you pour the concrete. No need to anchor with screws or bolts.  Pour the concrete around the drain first and work out toward your forms and the drain will stay in place.